# How do a comunication from viewController to appdelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I want to communicate with my appdelegate, in other words I want to send data from many views to AppDelegate, it's possible?

I found this code

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

of this question:
[Bi-Directional communication between ViewController and AppDelegate with swift 2 for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593574/bi-directional-communication-between-viewcontroller-and-appdelegate-with-swift-2)

it's possible with NSNotification to do the comunication?

Comment: It would be nice to know the reason for sending information. Depending on your needs, information can be shared on a controller to controller basis, or permanently stored with UserDefaults or CoreData. A little background on what type of information you want to pass would be helpful. Is it a class/struct you designed?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with NSNotification or without NSNotification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend you to use the NotificationCenter. They have some limitations.

1. From each ViewController, you have to use the post function and in App Delegate you have to add the observer. Then only you can use the post method of NotificationCenter. Like above David have shown you.
2. If you have to call different functions of App Delegate from different view Controllers then again you have to add different observers in App Delegate. After that you can call the different functions of App delegate.

But Using the above method which you have define in your question. You don't need to add the observer. With the help of this Instance you can call any method of App delegate. I would show you a example:-

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

 @UIApplicationMain
 @objc class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var isUpdate: Bool = false

func setValuesOfAppDelegate() {
    print("123")
}

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: UserDefaultKey.isAutoLogin) == false {
        startViewController()
    } else {
        goToRootViewAfterLogin()
    }

    AppUserDefaults.set(KEnglish, forKey: KSetLanguage)
    self.registerForPushNotifications(application)

    return true
  }
}
```

Examples how to use the App Delegate Variables and functions from the App delegate Instance. You can have a look over the code.

1. In first example am setting the variable of App Delegate from ClassA.
2. In Second Example am able to call the function of App Delegate from ClassB.
3. In Third Example am able to set the value of App Delegate Class variable and able to access the function on the same time.

   ```
   class ClassA: UIViewController {

       //MARK:- View Life Cycle
       override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
           appDelegate.isUpdate = true
       }
   }

   class ClassB: UIViewController {

        //MARK:- View Life Cycle
        override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
           appDelegate.setValuesOfAppDelegate()
        }   
   }

   class ClassC: UIViewController {

        //MARK:- View Life Cycle
        override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
           appDelegate.isUpdate = true
           appDelegate.setValuesOfAppDelegate()
       } 
    }
   ```

Comment: In this example, are you accessing the AppDelegate directly from within the view controllers? If so, wouldn't this basically be a singleton and you'd have to call something like `AppDelegate.appDelegate.isUpdate = true` rather than simply `appDelegate.isUpdate = true`?

Comment: Yes am accessing the appDelegate directly within the View Controllers. Its Depend upon you if you want to create the instance of AppDelegate in Struct. You can do that but am trying to explain the difference between Notification Center and the AppDelegate Class.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, `Notification` could do what you are trying to do. From within the view controllers, post a notification:

```swift
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "ViewControllerButtonPressed", object: nil)
    }
}
```

And then, within your `AppDelegate`, add a `Notification` observer to observe posts to this notification name:

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        ...

        //Add the observer
        //This observer will call the "doSomething" function every time NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "ViewControllerButtonPressed", object: nil) is called
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(doSomething), name: "ViewControllerButtonPressed", object: nil)
    }

    @objc func doSomething() {
        print("A button was pressed in one of your view controllers!")
    }

}
```

**An additional suggestion:**
To keep things more simple, you could extend `Notification.Name` to create static `String` values for the names:

```swift
public extension Notification.Name {
    static let ButtonPressed = Notification.Name("ViewControllerButtonPressed")
}
```

This could then replace

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "ViewControllerButtonPressed", object: nil)
```

with

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.ButtonPressed, object: nil)
```

and

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(doSomething), name: "ViewControllerButtonPressed", object: nil)
```

with

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(doSomething), name: NSNotification.Name.ButtonPressed, object: nil)
```

Implementing the above method is optional, but would prevent typos causing issues when using `Notification`s.